# Ruby on Rails app showing index of RAILS_ROOT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, passenger

I am deploying an app on Ubuntu 10 using Passenger 2.2.15, Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.8.7, and Apache 2.2.14. When I open http://localhost/appname it displays the contents of the app's root directory (/var/www/appname). Currently passenger and apache seem to be installed correctly, but this error persists.

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/appname is a logical link of /etc/apache2/sites-available/appname.

My files and their (relevant) contents:

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/appname**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/appname/public
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf**

```
<IfModule passenger_module>
   PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15
   PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
</IfModule>
```

**/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.load**

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

When I restart apache2, the following is left in the errors log file:
[Thu Sep 02 16:09:09 2010] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 02 16:09:10 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/2.2.15 PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations

Thanks for any help you guys can offer, been chewing on this a couple of hours now.

-RM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have other virtualhost with DOC_ROOT /var/www

Comment: Much abliged, sir. You fixed this problem (on to the next, big purple screen of death from rack waiting for me to debug). Thanks again!

Comment: Now I'm being greeted with "no such file to load -- initializer", much harder to configure this thing correctly on Ubuntu vs OSX. - Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

is your site only listed in

/etc/apache2/sites-available/appname

or also in

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/appname

?

Comment: It is also listed in sites-enabled as it is in the default file.